# updating listbox from combo box

Tags: c#

I imported access database into c#, created form with a combo-box that list all customers, created a list-box to show address details of that customer(2 different tables), how do i bind that combo-box to the list-box...

the relationship is 1-many (customer(1) -- address(many))

Answer (score 1):

Put the same source/DataSource/List in the 2 DataSource of your combo and list box dont forget to  bind them, if you put some code i could help a bit more

Answer (score 0):

i would do this on the `ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged` event. rebind your `ListBox.DataSource` with the `ComboBox.SelectedValue` of the ComboBox.